# C# Every item in array with every other item in same array

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have an array of items and what I'd like to do is some sort of a loop with which I would use every object inside that array and run a test function for every other remaining object in that array.

I don't want to use two of same objects twice, meaning that if A and B get checked B and A will not get checked.

Lets say i have an array of A B C D
Now what i want to do is

A B

A C

A D

B C

B D

C D

So that there is no 2 of same elements printing out twice.

Comment: can you show some **code** ?

Comment: you question seems confusing, but try using LINQ's `Distinct()` method.

Comment: Sounds like a standard combination problem. Have you tried looking for generating all combinations? There are plenty of StackOverflow posts that show how to do it.

Answer (score 5):

It's a simple nested loop:

```
int[] myArray = new int[1000];

for (int x = 0; x < myArray.Length; ++x)
{
    for (int y = x+1; y < myArray.Length; ++y)
    {
        // do something with x and y
    }
}
```

You should understand that for large arrays this can take a very long time. The number of combinations is `n*(n-1)/2`. So if your array contains 1,000 items you'll have almost 500,000 combinations to check.

Comment: No, this will then use x and y twice since X will be used once and then 2nd time when the object which is Y becomes X..

Comment: @user3025332: What do you mean? With 3 items, this will give `0,1`, `0,2`, and `1,2`. It will not duplicate a combination (that is, it will not give `1,0`, for example).

Comment: This loop is correct. Try stepping through it yourself, and pay close attention to how `y` is initialized.

Comment: I have updated OP with an example

Comment: This loop does exactly what you put in the OP, even in that order. Please try it out.